# Can we send only data payload from backend server for notifications in android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Well i am having issue while customizing my notification, in my case both notification payload and data payload is sent from backend and when the app is in background it automatically receive notification in device tray, for this i was asking do i send only the data payload and in that send required field to generate notification on app side?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Bbackend side just push without key `notification`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show notification in both foreground and background please use data payload only

Comment: but right now had discussion with backend guy,, he' s saying only data payload cant be sended from backend(along with notification payload is necessary like that)

Comment: as for more even from firebase console only data payload can't be sended alone.

Comment: No you can add both data and notification payload from backend. I am as our backend team has done it.In our case if we need to get both notification foregrounnd and background we need data payload itself